# Follower headroom question

Tags: voltage, distortion

I am designing a HiVoltage nmos source follower but I can't get the input headroom voltage I need. My supply is 300VDC I use an STF7N60M2 600V nmos. I would like to have my 200Vpp AC signal coming out at the source undistorted. But after 130Vpp (my limit) it start to distort.

Here is the circuit :

[image]

I am wondering is it even possible ? with these conditions (300V supply).

I don't understand how the divider resistors (Rg1 Rg2) affects the headroom. I googled for 3 days for this divider headroom relationship but It still not clear.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Most readers will not want to click through to another site to see your circuit, and if that link breaks your question won't have value to anyone who comes along later. Please draw your circuit using the built-in schematic editor.

Comment: Your schematic is fine. You just needed to use the image button on the edit toolbar, paste in the link, and it gets uploaded and inlined in your question. You should probably add another one showing actual voltages, component numbers and values.

Comment: What is your load resistance?

Comment: I added my schematic. It's 10k at the moment but It's not the the final load.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuUzZO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I see that you have set the gate voltage at

$$V_G = V_{DD} \cdot \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} = 225V$$

Therefore the voltage at the source will be around \$ V_S = 221V\$.

This means that the voltage at the source can swing up from \$221V\$ to \$300V\$, only by \$79V\$.

The negative swing is limited by the \$R_S\$ resistor and \$R_L\$.

$$V_{MAXneg} = V_S \cdot \frac{R_L}{R_S + R_L} \approx 73V$$

I hope that now you can see what you need to tweak to get desired voltage swing at the output.

At first, you could try \$R_1 = R_2 = 1M\Omega\$ and \$R_S = 3.3k\Omega\$

And do not forget about the power dissipation in transistor and in Rs resistance.

Also, have you considered the push-pull follower instead single-ended one?

Comment: Thank you very much. I know about the dissipation of Rs; don't worry.

Comment: Also I have seen some schematics include a low value series resitor after the voltage divider (at the gate of the mosfet). What is the use ?

Comment: This resistor is sometimes needed to separate the MOSFET gate capacitance from the rest of a circuit. Because sometimes MOSFET will oscillate without the gate resistor.